# JQuery: Create on change events for an unknown number (dynamic) fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

If I have a form that might have 1 or more sections for addresses crated with laravel forms: something like:

```
{{ Form::text('street1', '', ['class' => '']) }}
{{ Form::label('state1', 'State', ['class' => '']) }}
{{ Form::label('country1', 'Country', ['class' => '']) }}


{{ Form::text('street2', '', ['class' => '']) }}
{{ Form::select('state2', 'State', ['class' => '']) }}
{{ Form::select('country2', 'Country', ['class' => '']) }}
```

and a script that populates the state selector based on what country is selected. So if `country1` is set *USA* then the drop down list for `state1` will be only states from the US. I can do this by hardcoding my JQuery script with the IDs of each field. However, I would like to do this dynamically as there could be more than just 2 fields.

```
$('select[id="country1"]').on('change', function() { ... }
```

Is there a way that I can create a loop that generates `on.change` events for each set of fields?

Comment: Hi, one of solution is triger select change. f.e $('select').on('change', function(this){ this.attr('id'); // do your stuff with ID or class
})

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap each group in their own container. Then you can use a common class for each of the selects.

To get the associated state select look up to the wrapping container and find() the class for the state select that is inside it

```js
$('.country').change(function() {
  const $stateSelect = $(this).closest('.group').find('.state');

  getStates(this.value).then(states => {
    $stateSelect.html(() => states.map(el => new Option(el.txt, el.k)));
  });
});

// mock server request asynchronous method
function getStates(key) {
  const states={us:[{k:"al",txt:"Alabama"},{k:"hi",txt:"Hawaii"}],cdn:[{k:"ont",txt:"Ontario"},{k:"alb",txt:"Alberta"}]};
  return Promise.resolve(states[key]);
}
```

```css
.group { margin:0 2em 1em 2em; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding:1em}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  Country: <select class="country" name="country1">
    <option value=""> -Select Country</option>
    <option value="cdn">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">USA</option>
  </select>
 States: <select class="state" name="state1"></select>

</div>

<div class="group">
 Country:  <select class="country" name="country2">
    <option value=""> -Select Country</option>
    <option value="cdn">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">USA</option>
  </select>
 States: <select class="state" name="state2"></select>

</div>
```

Comment: very helpful. Will try it out later and let you know

Comment: how do get the value from an ajax response back to the caller function ` $.ajax({ url: '/resources/states/'+key, type: 'GET',  datatype: 'json', ))` so that it can be used in the promise like your `states` variable

Comment: I have tried $stateSelect.html(() => Object.keys(states).map((k) => new Option(states[k ], k)));   inside of the .ajax query but I would prefer to be able to have a standalone function that handles the call to the server as you have done in your example.

Comment: I only through that in to show how it could work. I have no idea what your data looks like. My main objective was to answer the question asked...how to isolate the state select associated with the specific country one

Comment: I know... but I was just asking for a little more help. Thanks anyway

Comment: Not sure what you are asking then

Answer (score 0):

No need to generates `on.change` events for each set of fields. You can  apply onChange event on all the `selects` and in the body of function you can get the current `select` being changed by using `this` and can do the stuff with that like

```
 $('select').on('change', function(){

     /* 
     for example you have different ids for different selects then you can 
     simply get the id of the current element to recognize it.
     */
    

   id = $(this).attr('id');

// then place the condition to recognize and do your stuff.

  if (id == 'country1'){
    // code stuff for country 1
  }elseif(id == 'country2')
  {
    // code stuff for country 2
  }

   value = this.value;// example get the value

});
```

**Edit**

No matter how many `select` you have, a unique identifier must have to be attach to it in terms if `id` or any `data-attribute`.

So you can try this as well if you dont want to use too many `if and else`,try giving numeric ids to country like `id=1` and related string concatenated ids to its states like `id=state1`.

Say your country `select` has an `id='1'` and your state `select` have `id='state1'` and so on for other country's `select`, then you can use the following snippet.*Note you can simply  dynamically generate `ids` with string concatenation with in a loop in order to create html elements.*

```
 $('select').on('change', function(){

     /* 
     for example you have different ids for different selects then you can 
     simply get the id of the current element to recognize it.
     */


   id = $(this).attr('id');// say if id=1 for country

// then get the respective state selector with 

 state = 'state'+id; // respective state selector identifier, state1
 stateSelector = "#"+state;

   $(stateSelector ).val();// example get the value of respective state or whatever.

});
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how I would then know which  of the country fields was selected and which state field to target with my function. How would I ensure that a change to `country1` targets `state1`?

Comment: @matthias check the updated answer hope it will help you

Comment: hi, so this is the problem I have. I don't know how many `county` I will have .. so it could be a list of 10 countries. What do I do then? i appreciate your help

Comment: Several problems in this solution. `this` is not a jQuery object but attr() is jQuery method. `this.val` will be undefined and `$(stateSelector ).val` is a function

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for pointing out the mistakes i have now amend them.

Comment: @matthias please have a look at the updated answer hope it will help you now.

Comment: Hi I am afk atm. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help.